# Volatility surface - "AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'expiration'

Tags: python, dataset, quantitative-finance

Working in Colab, starting to build an implied vol surface in Python for 0DTE options trades.  imported yfinance, pandas, numby successfully - can't find simple solution to this error?

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-31-494e77cf0df4> in <module>
----> 1 options = option_chains("ES")
      2 
      3 puts = [options["optionType"] == "put"]
      4 
      5 # print the expirations

1 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/generic.py in __getattr__(self, name)
   5485         ):
   5486             return self[name]
-> 5487         return object.__getattribute__(self, name)
   5488 
   5489     def __setattr__(self, name: str, value) -> None:

AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'expiration'
```

........................

code:

```
options = option_chains("SPY")

puts = [options["optionType"] == "put"]

# print the expirations
set(puts.expiration)

# select an expiration to plot
puts_at_expiry = puts[puts["expiration"] == "2022-12-2 23:59:59"]

# filter out low vols
filtered_puts_at_expiry = puts_at_expiry[puts_at_expiry.impliedVolatility >= 0.001]

# set the strike as the index so pandas plots nicely filtered_puts_at_expiry[["strike","impliedVolatility"]].set_index("strike").plot(title="Implied Volatility Skew", figsize=(7, 4))
```

guessing added these 2

```
from pandas_datareader import data as pdr
```

```
!pip install yfinance
```

in addition to yfinance